# How to disable SSL checking on Nginx?

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have some QA server for my website.
A year ago I've tried to make SSL connection to my production website so I've implemented it on the QA by nginx too.

Now it's expired and I don't want to renew it on the QA.

How can I do it without removing Nginx.
I've tried some things that I've googled but I didn't find something good.

It's still demanding the SSL checking, and this is the error that I'm getting when I've tried to load it:

```
    main.9b8be0e9.chunk.js:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://example.com:46/ws/....'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

**The nginx start of configuration...**

```
server {

listen 80;
#some trying
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;

server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
#I remove the s from the https...
return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;

}
```

I also have listeners on the port of the server and 443

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
> ```

With code 301 your have specified a **permanent** redirect to HTTPS. Browsers will have visited your site in the past will have cached this redirect and - since it was specified as permanent - will immediately use HTTPS without trying to use HTTP first, even if the user has explicitly entered the plain HTTP URL.

The server has no control of the browsers redirect cache except **adding** entries using 301. There is no way to force a browser to **delete** the entry again. See also [Force browsers to forget cached redirects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23397040/force-browsers-to-forget-cached-redirects)

Comment: So what I should do? If I will removed the nginx it won't solve it?

Comment: @lingar: if you completely disable HTTPS the request will fail. Maybe the browser will delete the cached entry after such a failure, maybe not. It's not a defined behavior. The safest way is actually to keep HTTPS enabled and renew the certificate